# Fast / Efficient Way to Decompose a Separable integer 2D Filter Coefficients without the SVD

Tags: filters, separability, 1d, 2d

I would like to be able to quickly determine whether a given 2D kernel of integer coefficients is separable into two 1D kernels with integer coefficients. E.g.

```
 2   3   2
 4   6   4
 2   3   2
```

is separable into

```
 2   3   2
```

and

```
 1
 2
 1
```

The actual test for separability seems to be fairly straightforward using integer arithmetic, but the decomposition into 1D filters with integer coefficients is proving to be a more difficult problem. The difficulty seems to lie in the fact that ratios between rows or columns may be non-integer (rational fractions), e.g. in the above example we have ratios of 2, 1/2, 3/2 and 2/3.

I don't really want to use a heavy duty approach like SVD because (a) it's relatively computationally expensive for my needs and (b) it still doesn't necessarily help to determine *integer* coefficients.

Any ideas ?

---

**FURTHER INFORMATION**

Coefficients may be positive, negative or zero, and there may be pathological cases where the sum of either or both 1D vectors is zero, e.g.

```
-1   2  -1
 0   0   0
 1  -2   1
```

is separable into

```
 1  -2   1
```

and

```
-1
 0
 1
```

Comment: I remember trying to figure this out way back in college. I almost succeeded, but I don't remember how. = ) I can't stop thinking about it now that you mentioned it!

Comment: @Phonon: heh - well keep thinking - I could use some inspiration on this one. ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing but for double or float values ?

Comment: @DiegoCatalano: see Denis's answer below, and the question he links to on math.stackexchange.com - I think that might work for the more general case of floating point coefficients.

Comment: @PaulR, How could one contact you on email? Thank You.

Comment: @Drazick: you can contact me via LinkedIn (see profile page).

Comment: Well, I don't have LinkedIn and it doesn't show any information unless you have an account.

Comment: OK, well I don't really want to give out my email address in a public forum. Maybe you could just post whatever questions you have on SO or DSP.SE - I watch various tags, e.g. `simd` and `fft`, so I'm sure to see them, and I'll answer if I can.

Comment: Seems someone calls this the «inverse outer product»:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have taken `@Phonon`'s answer and modified it somewhat so that it uses the GCD approach on just the top row and left column, rather than on row/column sums. This seems to handle pathological cases a little better. It can still fail if the top row or left column are all zeroes, but these cases can be checked for prior to applying this method.

```
function [X, Y, valid] = separate(M)    % separate 2D kernel M into X and Y vectors 
  X = M(1, :);                          % init X = top row of M
  Y = M(:, 1);                          % init Y = left column of M
  nx = numel(X);                        % nx = no of columns in M
  ny = numel(Y);                        % ny = no of rows in M
  gx = X(1);                            % gx = GCD of top row
  for i = 2:nx
    gx = gcd(gx, X(i));
  end
  gy = Y(1);                            % gy = GCD of left column
  for i = 2:ny
    gy = gcd(gy, Y(i));
  end
  X = X / gx;                           % scale X by GCD of X
  Y = Y / gy;                           % scale Y by GCD of Y
  scale = M(1, 1) / (X(1) * Y(1));      % calculate scale factor
  X = X * scale;                        % apply scale factor to X
  valid = all(all((M == Y * X)));       % result valid if we get back our original M
end
```

Many thanks to `@Phonon` and `@Jason R` for the original ideas for this.

Answer (score 10):

Got it! Posting MATLAB code, will post an explanation tonight or tomorrow

```
% Two original arrays
N = 3;
range = 800;
a = round( range*(rand(N,1)-0.5) )
b = round( range*(rand(1,N)-0.5) )

% Create a matrix;
M = a*b;
N = size(M,1);

% Sanity check
disp([num2str(rank(M)) ' <- this should be 1!']);

% Sum across rows and columns
Sa = M * ones(N,1);
Sb = ones(1,N) * M;

% Get rid of zeros
SSa = Sa( Sa~=0 );
SSb = Sb( Sb~=0 );

if isempty(SSa) | isempty(SSb)
    break;
end

% Sizes of array without zeros
Na = numel(SSa);
Nb = numel(SSb);

% Find Greatest Common Divisor of Sa and Sb.
Ga = SSa(1);
Gb = SSb(1);

for l=2:Na
    Ga = gcd(Ga,SSa(l));
end

for l=2:Nb
    Gb = gcd(Gb,SSb(l));
end

%Divide by the greatest common divisor
Sa = Sa / Ga;
Sb = Sb / Gb;

%Scale one of the vectors
MM = Sa * Sb;
Sa = Sa * (MM(1) / M(1));

disp('Two arrays found:')
Sa
Sb
disp('Sa * Sb = ');
Sa*Sb
disp('Original = ');
M
```

Comment: Thanks - this is great - I was lying awake last night thinking about factorising the coefficients etc but just using the GCD like this is a lot more simple and elegant. Unfortunately there is still one wrinkle to iron out - it needs to work with both positive and negative coefficients and this can lead to degenerate cases, e.g. `A=[-2 1 0 -1 2]; B=[2 -3 6 0 -1]; M=A'*B;`. The problem here is that `sum(A) = 0` so `Sb = [0 0 0 0 0]`. I'm going to try modifying your algorithm so that it uses the sum of *absolute* values of the coefficients and see if that helps. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: OK - it looks like you can still get the GCDs and do the scaling by using `abs(M)`, i.e. `Sa=abs(M)*ones(N,1); Sb=ones(1,N)*abs(M);` and then continue as above, but I can't yet see how to restore the signs to `Sa`, `Sb` at the end. I've added a pathological example that illustrates the problem in the original question above.

Comment: I think I have a working solution now - I've posted it as a separate answer, but the credit goes to you for the underlying idea. Thanks again !

Answer (score 7):

Maybe I'm trivializing the problem, but it seems like you could:

- Break the $N$-by-$M$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$ into rows $\mathbf{a_i}$, $i = 0, 1, \ldots , N-1$.
- For each row index $j > 0$:

  - Elementwise divide $\mathbf{a_j}$ by $\mathbf{a_0}$ to yield the ratio of each element in row $j$ to its counterpart in row zero $\mathbf{r_j}$. This would need to be done using floating-point or some other fractional arithmetic.
  - Inspect the elements in $\mathbf{r_j}$ to determine if they are constant. You'll need to allow for some tolerance in this comparison to allow for floating-point rounding.
  - If the values in $\mathbf{r_j}$ are constant, then row $\mathbf{a_j}$ is a scalar multiple of row $\mathbf{a_0}$. Store the ratio of row $j$ to row $0$ in a list $\mathbf{x}$.
  - If the ratio vector is not constant, then row $\mathbf{a_j}$ is a scalar multiple of row $\mathbf{a_0}$, so you will not be able to decompose the matrix in this way. Stop checking.
- If all of the rows were deemed to be constant multiples of row 0 in the tests above, then take the list of row ratio scalars $\mathbf{x}$ and normalize it by the smallest ratio:

$$
x_{k,norm} = \frac{x_k}{\min_{i=0}^{N-1} x_i}
$$

- After doing so, the normalized list of ratios $\mathbf{x_{norm}}$ will contain a value of 1 for the row that has the smallest norm. You want to see if you can scale this list in some way to yield a list that contains all integer coefficients. A brute-force approach could just do a linear search, that is, calculate:
  $$
  \mathbf{x_{scaled}} = K\mathbf{x_{norm}}, K = 1, 2, \ldots, M
  $$
  For each value of $K$, after calculating the scaled list of ratios, you would need to check each to see if they are integer-valued (again, with some tolerance). Set $M$ equal to the largest denominator that you're willing to look for in the inter-row ratios.

Not the most elegant method, and it's likely that there's a better way, but it should work, is pretty simple to implement, and should be relatively speedy for modestly-sized matrices.

Comment: Thanks - I think I was probably heading in something like this direction before I got bogged down in the details. It's not 100% clear to me that you'll always arrive at a solution using this method, but anyway, I should probably code this up and try it with a few examples. I have a hunch that it may need to be applied both row-wise and column-wise to see which yields the "best" solution. Thanks for taking the time to spell out the details - I'll get busy with it and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Couldn't you find the greatest common divisor of the first elements of the rows, and use that to determine your basis vector?

Comment: @JimClay: Yes, that's effectively what you're doing at the end, if you have that functionality available.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to find a separable approximation $x \otimes y \otimes z$
to your kernel $A$, and see how close it is.
Two ways of doing this, i.e. to minimize
$|A - x \otimes y \otimes z|$:
1) brute-force optimize $x\ y\ z$; this takes time ~ the sum, not the product, of their lengths
2) for fixed $y$ and $z$, the optimal $x$ is just a projection, so optimize
$x\ y\ z\ x\ y\ z\ ...$ in turn.

(From [approximate-a-convolution-as-a-sum-of-separable-convolutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210565/approximate-a-convolution-as-a-sum-of-separable-convolutions) 
 on math.stackexchange.)

Comment: Try not to answer questions with unexplained links. It is better to explain the necessary details in your answer and include the link only for reference; that way if the link breaks the essential details of the answer are still there.

Comment: @SamMaloney: I see no reason why that's necessary. The link explains everything in detail. It will still pop up in Q&A search. So why not?

Comment: @Naresh I only mention it because one of the goals of the stack exchange sites is to build up a repository of answered questions for future reference. So while I understand that this particular link is to another SE site and should be fairly safe, it is a general best practice not to count on links still working several years from now. Giving a general outline of these "two easy methods' in the answer would ensure that information is retained even if something happens to the linked question. As I said though, this was more of a general comment on best practices regarding links in answers.