# How to Check Separability of 2D Filter / Signal / Matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, linear-algebra, svd, separability

Given:

```
    x(n1,n2) = {1 ,n1=0,n2=0 ;
                2 ,n1=1,n2=0 ;
                3 ,n1=0,n2=1 ; 
                6 ,n1=1,n2=1 }
```

How could one prove it is separable?

Comment: By separable,  do you mean $x(n1,n2)=x1(n1)x2(n2)$ ?

Comment: If so, the matrix will be rank 1.  you can also have $x(n1,n2)=g(\sqrt{x1^2+x2^2})$

Comment: For integer case - https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/fast-efficient-way-to-decompose-separable-integer-2d-filter-coefficients.

Comment: Related to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35190.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nilesh Padhi, Welcome to the DSP Community.

The classic definition of separable means the data (2D) given by $ X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $ can be written as:

$$ X = \sigma u {v}^{T} $$

Where $ \sigma \in \mathbb{R} $, $ u \in \mathbb{R}^{m} $ and $ v \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $.
This is called Rank 1 Matrix.

How can you get those parameters and vectors given $ X $?
Well, the [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) (SVD) is here to save the data.

The SVD of $ X $ is given by:

$$ X = U \Sigma {V}^{T} = \sum {\sigma}_{i} {u}_{i} {v}_{i}^{T} $$

You can see those match when $ {\sigma}_{j} = 0 $ for $ j \geq 2 $.
So what you should do is the following:

```
epsThr = 1e-7;
[mU, mD, mV] = svd(mX);
vD = diag(mD);
if(all(vD(2:end) < epsThr))
    vU = mU(:, 1);
    vV = mV(:, 1);
end
```

We checked if indeed the singular value of 2 and onward are small.
If they do (You can decide to what degree of small by `epsThr`) then it is separable and the vectors are `vU` and `vV`.

In your case:

```
mX = [1, 3; 2, 6];
[mU, mD, mV] = svd(mX);

vD = diag(mD);
disp(vD);
```

The result is:

```
vD =

    7.0711
    0.0000
```

Since `vD` values are zero besides the first element (Only single non vanishing Singular Value) it is separable.

Indeed you can see that:

```
mD(1) * mU(:, 1) * mV(:, 1).'

ans =

    1.0000    3.0000
    2.0000    6.0000
```

As expected.

This method is really useful in Image Processing when we want to convolve with 2D kernel and we find it is separable and hence we can apply the 2D convolution using 2 1D convolutions (Along Columns / Rows).

In that case we define $ \hat{u} = \sqrt{{\sigma}_{1}} u $ and $ \hat{v} = \sqrt{{\sigma}_{1}} v $ where $ {\sigma}_{1} $ is the Singular Value.
Then we convolve $ \hat{u} $ along columns and $ \hat{v}^{T} $ along rows.

Comment: @Fat32, Thank you for fixing the Typo.

Comment: Very nice answer indeed. Note that there's a *slight* mismatch between the actual components, *u* ,*v* for $h = u \cdot v'$ and their computed counterparts *hu*,*hv* **if** computed from $hu = \sqrt{D(1)} mU$ and $hv = \sqrt{D(1)} mV$  (But the mismatch is cancelled through the row-column convolutions and yields a very accurate result. Yet if individual components are used for some other purposes, the slight mismatch shall be considered for accuracy sensitive applications.

Comment: @Fat32, Well, for Convolution usually we do as you wrote and multiply $ u $ and $ v $ by the square root of the Singular Value. I will add that.

Comment: hmm, either I stated it not very clear, or you misunderstood. If you will eventually perform the 2D conolution (in the separation manner) then *do not* compute *hu* and *hv*. Just use the first columns of U and V matrices and multiply the result by $\sigma_1$. Because the former would introduce more errors than the latter. If you, on the other hand, want to use the *individual* 1D filters for some other reasons, then the multiplication by $\sqrt{\sigma_1}$ is required...

Comment: @Fat32, On the contrary. In Image processing you don't want to do 3 passes. You use those variables (You can watch MATLAB's `imfilter()`. In Linear Algebra you usually leave at the form of the SVD decomposition in order ot keep $ u $ and $ v $ part of orthonormal basis.

Comment: you don't have to do 3 passes if you are so much into efficiency. You can merge that $\sigma_1$ into juts one of those 1D filters and perform just two passes ;-) And it will be more accurate and more efficient than merging $\sqrt{\sigma_1}$ into both filters and doing 2 passes...

Comment: Yep, In practice you do that. You should only multiply one of them (Thugh, as I wrote, MATLAB's `imfilter()` multiply each by the square root [At least in MATLAB R2018a]). I wasn't into the small details of technicality but into the idea. Thank You.